# Setting attributes of elements then returning result as a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, html-parsing, nokogiri

I have some HTML, like this:

```
html = "<h1>Title One</h1>\n\n<p>blah blah</p>\n\n<h1>Title Two</h1>\n\n<p>blah blah</p>\n"
```

I need to give an id attribute to each `h1` element, where the value of the id is the text of the `h1`, and then return the whole thing as a string again, so the result is like this:

```
"<h1 id="title-one">Title One</h1>\n\n<p>blah blah</p>\n\n<h1 id="title-two">Title Two</h1>\n\n<p>blah blah</p>\n"
```

I've tried many different things, and I've been able to set the attributes, but not turn it back into a string.

Basically, I want to do something like this, but obviously this doesn't work:

```
new_html = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html).xpath('//body').children do |el|
  if el.name == 'h1'
    id = el.children.text.parameterize
    el.set_attribute('id', id)
  end
end
new_html.to_s
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making it *much* too hard. Consider this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = "<h1>Title One</h1>\n\n<p>blah blah</p>\n\n<h1>Title Two</h1>\n\n<p>blah blah</p>\n"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html)

doc.search('h1').each do |h1|
  h1['id'] = h1.text.tr(' ', '-')
end

puts doc.to_html

# >> <h1 id="Title-One">Title One</h1>
# >> 
# >> <p>blah blah</p>
# >> 
# >> <h1 id="Title-Two">Title Two</h1>
# >> 
# >> <p>blah blah</p>
```

The rest of how to make the ID values look how you want is left for you to figure out.

> I've been able to set the attributes, but not turn it back into a string.

What's the difference between HTML and a string? HTML *is* a string, so use `to_html`.